# How do I prevent Nokogiri from adding unnecessary HTML tags?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, nokogiri

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this code that is meant to get the content of a URL

```
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

Sometimes a URL will return HTML but sometimes it will return JSON.  I do not know in advance.  What I have noticed is that when the URL returns JSON, Nokgiri adds all these HTML tags in front of it.  Here is what appears in a browser:

```
{"list":[{"u":"1459808276_000001","i":"1459184695_000001","pid":"RDE8UZZZ”,”fname":"Alexi","lname”:”Jones”,”sex":"F","city":"Eugene","country":"US","country_iso":"us","course":"8k","class":"elite","race":"8K","name":"Alexi Jones”,”_ver":"14","tag":"0000001","bib":"1"}],"info":{"first":"1","last":"1","total":"1","cacheVer":"0~0"}}
```

However when I execute Nokogiri, this is returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>{"list":[{"u":"1459808276_000001","i":"1459184695_000001","pid":"RDE8UZZZ”,”fname":"Alexi","lname”:”Jones”,”sex":"F","city":"Eugene","country":"US","country_iso":"us","course":"8k","class":"elite","race":"8K","name":"Alexi Jones”,”_ver":"14","tag":"0000001","bib":"1"}],"info":{"first":"1","last":"1","total":"1","cacheVer":"0~0"}}</p></body></html>
```

How do I prevent Nokogiri from adding extra stuff?  I just want it to return exactly what is returned to a browser.

When I try `doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(open(url))` as recommend by another SO answer, I get the error:

```
error: undefined method `strip' for #<StringIO:0x007ff8acb34c30>
```

Comment: Please format your question for readability. The effort you put in helps us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri assumes you've already determined whether you're receiving appropriate content for parsing. It's up to you to check prior to passing it to Nokogiri.

Don't use

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

You can look at the returned HTTP headers for the "CONTENT-TYPE", which should be "application/json" for a JSON response, or "TEXT/HTML" for HTML. The [OpenURI documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html#module-OpenURI-label-Example) has the following example:

```
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en") {|f|
  f.each_line {|line| p line}
  p f.base_uri         # <URI::HTTP:0x40e6ef2 URL:http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/>
  p f.content_type     # "text/html"
  p f.charset          # "iso-8859-1"
  p f.content_encoding # []
  p f.last_modified    # Thu Dec 05 02:45:02 UTC 2002
}
```

Or, you can look at the first character of the returned body, which will tell you whether it's HTML/XML or JSON. The first two will start with `<` and JSON will start with either `[` or `{`.

Something like this would be a decent start:

```
content = open('http://www.example.com').read

if content.lstrip[0] == '<'
  # it's XML/HTML so parse it with Nokogiri
else
  # it's JSON so parse it with the JSON parser
end
```